# Dropdown and checkboxes with Selenium (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to auto fill a registration on adidas and am not sure how to select checkboxes and especially dropdowns for DOB:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/MyAccount-Register")
```

This is whats not working for the checkbox:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ffCheckbox').click()
```

I have no idea how to complete the dropdown for DOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to handle target `<fieldset>` you first need to switch to appropriate `iframe`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="sso-iframe"]'))
```

Then you can handle required drop-down like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='DD']").click() # Open drop-down
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[@data-val="1"]'))).click() # select first day
```

To click on checkbox:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@id="consentLabel"]').click()
```

Comment: The checkbox works, but doesnt click the correct one and the dropdown gets clicked but says the elements in the dropdown are not visible.

Comment: Check updated answer to select option from dropdown. Also I don't know what is "correct" check-box. Just change `XPath` to check exact check-box

Comment: For some reason it wont select a month but will select day and year. It will even open up the dropdown menu.

Comment: Are you trying same `XPath` for month, e.g. `'//span[@data-val="1"]'` and getting `ElementNotVisibleException`?

Comment: span data-val="...">1</span> is not clickable at point (44, 208). Other element would receive the click: <h2>...</h2>

Comment: This is because you're trying to click day element actually... Try `'(//span[@data-val="1"])[2]'`

Comment: Thank you, do you know how i would scroll down on 'YY' to 1990?

Comment: Try `year = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[@data-val="1990"]'))); driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', year)`

Comment: says ';' is an invalid identifier

Comment: No, you don't have to use it. It's just a code lines separator. Use this code as 2 lines without `;`

Comment: year = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//spa‌​n[@data-val="1990"]'‌​)))
                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: hm... this is weird... I cannot check it today. I'll try to check tomorrow. Let me know if you solve this issue. Or you can submit new ticket about this issue to get solution ASAP